# Unable to run dev- server (npm)

Tags: npm, symfony4

For some reason i cant launch npm run dev-server
Please notice that i'm sudo

[image]

If someone have a solution to solve this problem please, let me know.
Edit : Does someone know where is this .sh ?

Comment: the error says `permission denied`. are you sure you have that your .sh file has the needed permission?

Comment: i'm in sudo mode :o

Comment: please can you tell me the position of the .sh file